# Pass argument from main() to different function - Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments, program-entry-point

I am experimenting with the `argparse` module and I am having trouble understanding how to pass arguments from the parser constructed in `main()` to a new function that will use the arguments. I have tried reading some books and documentation on this topic, but I only feel more confused. I have pasted my code below.

`CODE:`

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--skip", "-s", help="Skip updates to configuration.", 
                       action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()


def config_check(*pass args here from main*):
    if args.skip:
        print("Not making modifications!")
    else:
        print("Making modifications!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `config_check(args)` from `main`?

Comment: Your main function isn’t special in any way. You call functions and pass arguments to them just as from other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like how you would pass any other argument.

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--skip", "-s", help="Skip updates to configuration.", 
                       action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    config_check(args)


def config_check(args):
    if args.skip:
        print("Not making modifications!")
    else:
        print("Making modifications!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```